# How do I use Postman to create oAuth nonce, timestamp & signature?

Tags: authentication, twitter, oauth, postman, postman-native-app

I am looking at the Account Activity API and can see that I need to create a signature 
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html

This basically consists of the `oauth_nonce` ,`oauth_timestamp` & the `oauth_signature` use in the following request to the Twitter API.

`curl --request POST --url 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/webhooks.json?url=<URL>' --header 'authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<CONSUMER_KEY>", oauth_nonce="GENERATED", oauth_signature="GENERATED", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="GENERATED", oauth_token="<ACCESS_TOKEN>", oauth_version="1.0"'`

However I'd like to have this process working through the Postman API client - does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Are you searching for a proper configuration for this curl command in Postman, or do you want to know how to authenticate with Postman over the twitter api?

Comment: It can generate these for you : [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization/#oauth-10). Or you can use twurl for a more CLI experience.

Comment: thanks @osowskit if you want to add that link as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 2):

Postman has [instructions for creating an OAuth 1.0 Authorization Header](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization/#oauth-10) and will generate these for you.

Alternatively, [Twurl](https://github.com/twitter/twurl/blob/master/README.md#twurl) provides a curl-like CLI experience that may be a suitable alternative as it helps handle authentication headers for you.